# A question about transforming graphs

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm studying for a test I have tomorrow and I have a question about a review question in my book. I've never tried transforming functions with more than one $x$ value and I'm at a bit of a loss. Google searching and experimenting on Wolfram Alpha haven't helped.

I have a graph with the function $y = \sqrt{3x – x^2}$ that looks like this:

[image]

And I need to write a transformed function that looks like this:

[image]

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  You can break the transformation up into three steps.

1. Turn the graph upside down.
2. Move it one unit downwards.
3. Move it $4$ units to the left.

Can you put these successively into algebraic language?

Answer (score 0):

Hint : The first graph is a semicircle with centre at (1.5,0) and radius = 1.5 . The second graph is another semicircle with radius 1.5, and centre (-2.5, -1). This means that you have to transform the coordinates such that the centers aline and then choose the negative half of the circle you get. $x' = x - 4$ and $y' = y - 1$ would work.